# PLSQL: BEFORE INSERT Trigger

Tags: trigger, plsql

I am attempting to write my first trigger statement. I am trying to create a trigger that performs a SELECT to get my MAX_TOW_WEIGHT for a LOCO_CLASS, then compare that weight to the TRAIN_WEIGHT. If the comparison fails (that is, TRAIN_WEIGHT > MAX_TOW_WEIGHT) the code would need to throw a user-defined exception, which the code which executed the INSERT or UPDATE would need to be written to handle. I have done the following which is most probably wrong though it is an attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOCOWEIGHT 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Locomotive_Class
REFERENCING NEW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      SELECT Train_Weight FROM locomotive
   IF (MAX_TARE_WEIGHT > MAX_TOW_WEIGHT) THEN
       RAISE cError;    
EXCEPTION
WHEN cError THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_EXCEPTION('Train weight has exceeded max tow weight');
END;
```

Tables for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE Locomotive
 (Loco_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Serial_No integer UNIQUE,
  Loco_Class_No integer
    REFERENCES Locomotive_Class(Loco_Class_No),
  Loco_name varchar2(20));


CREATE TABLE Locomotive_Class
 (Loco_Class_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Max_Tow_Weight float NOT NULL,
  Loco_Class_Len float NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried compiling it so that you know where the syntax errors are?

Comment: There isn't even a `Train_Weight` column in the `Locomotive` table!

Comment: @Phil I updated the question it was suppose to be `MAX_TARE_WEIGHT` my fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things.

1) Your trigger doesn't look right - I think you need the trigger to be on the `locomotive` table, rather than the `locamotive_class` table, and have a newly inserted/updated train have its maximum weight checked against the maximum weight for the class.

2) There is no `train_weight` column in the `locomotive table`.

Assuming the above is true, this is the trigger code you require:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LOCOWEIGHT 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON locomotive
REFERENCING NEW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  MAX_WEIGHT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT max_tow_weight INTO MAX_WEIGHT
  FROM locomotive_class
  WHERE loco_class_no = :new.loco_class_no;

   IF :new.train_weight > MAX_WEIGHT THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Train weight has exceeded max tow weight');
  END IF;
END;
```

Along with:

```
alter table locomotive add ( train_weight number ) ;
```

Comment: I also want something like this. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300102/create-before-insert-trigger-in-oracle-and-implement-in-asp-net-web-form

Answer (score 0):

Your example tables is lacking the Train_Weight column you seem to be referencing in your trigger.
I'd also think that the trigger should be on the Locomotive table
So, I assume this is the correct structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Locomotive_Class
 (Loco_Class_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Max_Tow_Weight float NOT NULL,
  Loco_Class_Len float NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Locomotive
 (Loco_No integer,
  Serial_No integer,
  Loco_Class_No integer References Locomotive_Class(Loco_Class_no),
  Train_Weight float,
  Loco_name varchar2(20));
```

The easies way is to simply do this ( I reversed the comparison operator for the Train_weight, since that seemed more logical ):

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOCOWEIGHT 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Locomotive
REFERENCING NEW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF ( :new.Train_Weight > (SELECT MAX_TOW_WEIGHT FROM locomotive_class where Loco_Class_No = :new.Loco_Class_No) ) THEN
   raise_application_error( -20001, 'Train weight has exceeded max tow weight' );
END;
```

But if you want, you can do it by first defining a custom exception and then raising it and recatching it within the same code. That seems a little redundant, but then you'd do it like this:

```
declare cError EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( cError, -20001 );

begin
  raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
  exception when cError then 
    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
end;
```

then you can raise it from within your trigger.

Then your trigger would look something like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOCOWEIGHT 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Locomotive
REFERENCING NEW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF ( :new.Train_Weight > (SELECT MAX_TOW_WEIGHT FROM locomotive_class where Loco_Class_No = :new.Loco_Class_No) )  THEN
    RAISE cError;    

  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN cError THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_EXCEPTION(-20002, 'Train weight has exceeded max tow weight');
END;
```

Comment: `(SELECT Train_Weight FROM locomotive)` -- You're selecting every row in the table. Why? Certainly not correct.

Comment: That's true, it lacks the where clause. THe trigger should probably also be on the Locomotive table, since this doesn't really make much sense as is. 
I'll modify my query